# Text stuck next to navBAR

Tags: css, html, navbar, navigationbar

I'm trying to view text under the navBAR, but it just appears straight next to the navBAR buttons. I've tried some margin properties in css, but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks in advance!!

```
<html>
<title>title</title>

<head>
    <img src="img/logo.png">
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
    .narBAR{margin:0 auto; width:1080px;}
    .navBAR ul {padding:0px;}
    .navBAR ul li {float:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <body background="untitled.png">
    <div class="navBAR">
    <ul>                                    
    <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Amroo/Desktop/new%201.html#'><img src="img/home.png"></a></li>

    <ul>
    <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Amroo/Desktop/libarary%20one.html'><img src="img/ourbooks.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src="img/books.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href='#'><img src="img/login.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src="img/contact.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
    <form action="file:///C:/Users/Amroo/Desktop/new%201.html/search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search......"/>                                           
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>                                   
    </form>
    </div>


    <h1>text</h1>

    <img src="blog/img/mars.jpeg"> 

    <h3>text</h3>       
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS has a wrong class `.narBAR`:

```
.narBAR{margin:0 auto; width:1080px;}
```

Also there are errors in your code. You can't have `<img>` in your `<head>` so place this `<img src="img/logo.png">` in your `<body>`.

And use css background instead of `<body background="untitled.png">`.
For example:

```
body{
    background-image: url(untitled.png);
}
```

Although your code should work fine you can get described issue due to images so set `overflow: hidden` for `.navBAR`

Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kdmvxrmx/